# Vue how to add form repeater in another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some problems with Vue form repeaters.

I want to build one form repeater in another one. The first one works as expected but another (inside the first one) don't work for some reason.

I think that the problem is that I'm not doing something with key's, but here I am looking here for help, I tried some ways but it's always either repeating the first form or it's not working at all.

So here is my template code:

```
    <!-- Start first repeater -->
  <div v-for="(field, index) in form.first" v-bind:key="index" class="first-one" :style="{animation: 'fadeIn 0.5s'}">
    
    <!-- I'm adding some inputs to have some differences, using bootstrap -->

    <b-form-input color="success" v-model="field.first-repeater1" name="first" 
      type="text" />
    <b-form-input color="success" v-model="field.first-repeater2" name="second" />
    
    
    <!-- And now I will start second repeater inside this one -->

    <div v-for="(field2, iindex) in form.first.second" v-bind:key="iindex" class="sec-one" :style="{animation: 'fadeIn 0.5s'}">

       <b-form-input color="success" v-model="field2.second_repeater_form1" name="second_repeater1" type="number" />
       <b-form-input color="success" v-model="field2.second_repeater_form2" name="second_repeater2" />
   </div> <!-- Closing second repeater -->

  <b-button v-ripple.400="'rgba(113, 102, 240, 0.15)'" variant="outline-primary" pill @click="addSecondRepeater(index)">Button to add second repeater</b-button>

  <div> <!-- Closing first repeater -->

  <b-button v-ripple.400="'rgba(113, 102, 240, 0.15)'" variant="outline-primary" pill @click="addFirstRepeater">Button to add first repeater</b-button>
```

As you can see I'm passing index of first repeater to second.
So I have one state `form.first` where I need to store every information that is in those fields, and I will show at the end how it should looks like.

So let's take a look into a scripts:

State looks like so:

```
    form: {
           first: [{
               second: []
           }],
    },
    
    // Adding fields for first repeater, and it works fine.
    
    addFirstRepeater: function () {
                this.form.first.push({
                    first-repeater1: '',
                    first-repeater2: '',
                });
            },
    
   // Here is the error
    addSecondRepeater: function (index) {
                this.form.first[index].push({
                    second: {
                        second_repeater_form1: '',
                        second_repeater_form2: '',
                    }
                });
            },
```

So in this case for function `addSecondRepeater` it will give an error like:

> this.form.first[index].push is not a function

And if I remove `[index]` it will repeat the first form.

Here is the example on codepen https://codepen.io/rade-ilijev/pen/zYNvgqK
Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are pushing into an object not an array. Your default state value is

```
    form: {
       first: [{
           second: []
       }],
    },
```

You see the element in 'first' is not an array its an object. When addFirstRepeater is being called it's adding an object in the array. So in addSecondRepeater, this.form.first[index] points to an object not an array, and push() function is available with arrays not objects.

If you intent to use only 1 element in your main array (which I assume you do as I can see it in code) you may add this to addSecondRepeater

```
 this.form.first[0][index].push()
```

instead of

```
this.form.first[index].push()
```

Where 'index' is the key of the key value pair in the object at 0th index of array 'first'

Comment: So what can I actually do here? It's strange that in first repeater it works and in second it don't.

Comment: Well codepin seems to have a different variant of code, however, I have made some edits to my answer. Have a look

Comment: Well it's kinda same, but this.form.first[0][index].push() is still not working